# Showing a Image from a exsisting img tag without calling the server again. chrome extension javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome-extension, browser-cache

I creating a chrome extension and have come across an issue,

I have a bunch of items like this on a webpage:

```
<tr id="item1">
    <a id="item text">TITLE</a>
    <img src="SERVER/image1.jpg">
</tr>
```

I want to take all of these and create new items that show this information easier and any new items that have appeared.

So my code takes the item and gets the img src and saves it,

I then create my own div element and img element and insert the "item1" img src

into a element like below:

```
<div id="newItem1 container">
    <a id"newItem text> THIS IS THE ITEM TEXT</a>
    <img id"newItem img" src"The taken img src from the other element"/>
</div>
```

However, when I do this I think it calls to the image location to display it, Now imagine doing this 1000 times to 1000 items, It's basically DDOS-ing the image location server.

## MORE DETAILED EXAMPLE

IF the image src on the webpage item is

```
https://imgur.com/gallery/OM1jAhs
```

my chrome extension would grab this and then created a container element and inside the img element set the img src to:

```
https://imgur.com/gallery/OM1jAhs
```

and if another item on the webpage has appeared with a different img src:

```
https://imgur.com/gallery/W0JfyHW
```

My chrome extension will grab this and create another img element and set the created img src to:

```
https://imgur.com/gallery/W0JfyHW
```

The webpage has made 2 calls to the image location and I've made another 2 calls, If there was 750 items (which there is approximately) I would make another 750 calls, which the webpage just halts me and says "no, wtf you doing", kinda :).

## What do I want to know?

Is there a way I can access the img without calling the image location again? I guess because I've visited the webpage and viewed the image it must have been stored in my browser cache or something.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning the cached version already? Look at your network tab and in the transferred tab you should see "cached".
Otherwise you have to configure how your server caches your images.

Comment: There's no way usually to read the image data because it can be done only via Canvas API which won't work in most cases due to images having cross-origin URLs in relation to the web page. And there's no need usually because the browser should be caching the images as noted above.